# ERROR sun.misc when upgrade to karaf 4.X from karaf 3.X

Tags: osgi, hazelcast, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, karaf

We have problems that block us.
Our project in Apache karaf 3.0.3, cellar 3.0.3 works very well. Now we upgrade to Apache karaf 4.2.0 and Apache cellar 4.1.0. and I see this **error**

> [activator-1-thread-2] ERROR
>   org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.BootFeaturesInstaller -
>   Error installing boot features
>   org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve root:
>   missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=OUR_FEATURE;
>   type=karaf.feature; version="[18.12.4,18.12.4]";
>   filter:="(&(osgi.identity=OUR_FEATURE)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=18.12.4)(version<=18.12.4))"
>   [caused by: Unable to resolve OUR_FEATURE/18.12.4: missing requirement
>   [OUR_FEATURE/18.12.4] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=cellar;
>   type=karaf.feature  [caused by: Unable to resolve cellar/4.1.0:
>   missing requirement [cellar/4.1.0] karaf.cellar.provider  [caused by:
>   Unable to resolve cellar-hazelcast/4.1.0: missing requirement
>   [cellar-hazelcast/4.1.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=hazelcast;
>   type=karaf.feature; version="[3.8.1,3.8.1]"  [caused by: Unable to
>   resolve hazelcast/3.8.1: missing requirement [hazelcast/3.8.1]
>   osgi.identity; osgi.identity=com.hazelcast; type=osgi.bundle;
>   version="[3.8.1,3.8.1]"; resolution:=mandatory 
>   **[caused by: Unable to resolve com.hazelcast/3.8.1: missing requirement [com.hazelcast/3.8.1] osgi.wiring.package;
>   filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=sun.misc)"]**]]]]*
>   *at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolutionError.toException(ResolutionError.java:42)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.doResolve(ResolverImpl.java:391)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:377)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:331)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:248)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:388)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1025)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$13(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:964)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl$$Lambda$75/1531068986.call(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:?]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:?]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [?:?]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [?:?]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:?]

As we see, the error comes from ***com.hazelcast, version 3.8.1***

Indeed, In the past, we use ***karaf cellar and karaf 3.0.3***, they use ***com.hazelcast/hazelcast/version 3.4.2*** (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hazelcast/hazelcast/3.4.2)

Now with ***karaf 4.2.0 and cellar 4.1.0***, they use ***com.hazelcast/hazelcast-all/3.8.1
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hazelcast/hazelcast-all/3.8.1***
and this version cause this error

Here is content of our features.xml file

```
<repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.cellar/apache-karaf-cellar/4.1.0/xml/features</repository>
<feature name="OUR_FEATURE" version="18.12.4" description="Our description">
    <feature>cellar</feature>
    <feature version="${project.version}">other_features</feature>
</feature>
```

We tried to search in the target directory after installing (mvn clean install) and find these features in the target folder

```
<feature name="OUR_FEATURE" version="18.12.4" description="Our description">
    <feature>cellar</feature>
    <feature version="18.12.4">other_features</feature>
</feature>

<feature name="cellar" description="Karaf clustering" version="4.1.0">
    <feature dependency="true">cellar-hazelcast</feature>
    <feature>cellar-shell</feature>
    <feature>cellar-config</feature>
    <feature>cellar-bundle</feature>
    <feature>cellar-features</feature>
    <feature>cellar-kar</feature>
    <requirement>
        karaf.cellar.provider
    </requirement>
</feature>

<feature name="cellar" description="Karaf clustering" version="4.1.0">
    <feature dependency="true">cellar-hazelcast</feature>
    <feature>cellar-shell</feature>
    <feature>cellar-config</feature>
    <feature>cellar-bundle</feature>
    <feature>cellar-features</feature>
    <feature>cellar-kar</feature>
    <requirement>
        karaf.cellar.provider
    </requirement>
</feature>

<feature name="cellar-hazelcast" description="Cellar implementation based on Hazelcast" version="4.1.0">
    <feature version="3.8.1">hazelcast</feature>
    <feature version="4.1.0">cellar-core</feature>
    <bundle>mvn:org.apache.karaf.cellar/org.apache.karaf.cellar.hazelcast/4.1.0</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.apache.karaf.cellar/org.apache.karaf.cellar.utils/4.1.0</bundle>
    <capability>
        karaf.cellar.provider;provider:=hazelcast
    </capability>
</feature>

<feature name="hazelcast" description="In memory data grid" version="3.8.1">
    <configfile finalname="/etc/hazelcast.xml">mvn:org.apache.karaf.cellar/apache-karaf-cellar/4.1.0/xml/hazelcast</configfile>
    <bundle>mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec/1.1.1</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.eclipsesource.minimal-json/minimal-json/0.9.2</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.hazelcast/hazelcast-all/3.8.1</bundle>
</feature>
```

In our src/main/distribution/etc/config.properties, we have already following config:
***org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=sun.misc***

org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot,org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot.principal,org.apache.karaf.management.boot,sun.*,com.sun.*,javax.transaction,javax.transaction.*,javax.xml.crypto,javax.xml.crypto.*

*org.osgi.framework.executionenvironment=J2SE-1.8,JavaSE-1.8,J2SE-1.7,JavaSE-1.7,J2SE-1.6,JavaSE-1.6,J2SE-1.5,JavaSE-1.5,J2SE-1.4,JavaSE-1.4,J2SE-1.3,JavaSE-1.3,J2SE-1.2,,JavaSE-1.2,CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0,J2ME,OSGi/Minimum-1.1,OSGi/Minimum-1.0*

In our src/main/distribution/etc/custom.properties, we have following configs:

*karaf.systemBundlesStartLevel=50
org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra = org.apache.karaf.branding*

Please help us solve this problem.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Boot delegation is used when bundles load classes but do not define an Import-Package statement for them.

In your case hazelcast has an Import-Package statement. So to make this work you must export the package from the system bundle.

To do this edit `config.properties` and add `sun.misc` to `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. As you see, I have already wrote:
"In our src/main/distribution/etc/config.properties, we have already following config: org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=sun.misc"

But it doesnot work. So I try with Boot delegation, It doesnot work either

Comment: Exporting form the system bundle is the only way this can work. Maybe there is a small error in the config and it is not processed. I just started a plain karaf 4.2.0 and installed the transaction feature and the hazelcast bundle. It worked out of the box. The sun.misc package was already exported.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where you put your config.properties? My directory layout is like that
my-deployement/pom.xml
my-deployement/src/main/distribution/binaries/setenv
my-deployement/src/main/distribution/etc
my-deployement/src/main/distribution/filtered-resources

Here is the list of file in my-deployement/src/main/distribution/etc folder:
- config.properties,custom.properties, keys.properties,org.apache.cxf.osgi.cfg, org.apache.karaf.management.cfg, org.apache.karaf.shell.cfg, org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg, org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg, system.properties, user.properties

Comment: Here is the list of file in my-deployement/src/main/distribution/etc folder: - config.properties,custom.properties, keys.properties,org.apache.cxf.osgi.cfg, org.apache.karaf.management.cfg, org.apache.karaf.shell.cfg, org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg, org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg, system.properties, user.properties

Comment: Here is the list of file in my-deployement/src/main/distribution/filtered-resources:
org.apache.karaf.cellar.groups.cfg, org.apache.karaf.cellar.node.cfg, org.apache.karaf.features.cfg, org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg

Comment: You can see a content of our config.properties above, and its position in our folder layout

Answer (score 0):

Here is extraction of my config.properties

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages= \
 org.osgi.framework.startlevel;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.0", \
 org.osgi.framework.wiring;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1", \
 org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1", \
 org.osgi.framework.hooks.service;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1", \
 org.osgi.framework.hooks.resolver;uses:="org.osgi.framework.wiring";version="1.0", \
 org.osgi.framework.launch;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1", \
 org.osgi.framework.namespace;uses:="org.osgi.resource";version="1.0", \
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.7", \
 org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving;uses:="org.osgi.framework.wiring";version="1.0",\
 org.osgi.resource;version="1.0",org.osgi.service.url;version="1.0",\
 org.osgi.service.startlevel;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1",\
 org.osgi.service.packageadmin;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.2",\
 org.osgi.service.url;version="1.0", \
 org.osgi.util.tracker;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.5.1", \
 org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot;version="4.2.0", \
 org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot.principal;version="4.2.0", \
 org.apache.karaf.management.boot;version="4.2.0", \
 org.apache.karaf.version;version="4.2.0", \
 ${jre-${java.specification.version}}



org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=sun.misc
```